# Update UI with event callback in C#

Tags: c#, xaml, callback, uwp

After searching a while on this, I found so many sources but no one that can help me... Sorry if I missed a post on that.

I have an UWP application that should start a camera when I talk.

The speech recognition is ok ; a button to start the camera is ok too. But, call to `VisualStateManager.GoToState()` on an speech event callback fail :/

I wrote a cleaned example of my scripts (all 'using' removed too):

---

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Alfred.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Alfred"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FaceProcessingState">
                <VisualState x:Name="Stopped" />
                <VisualState x:Name="Playing">
                    <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Target="btnPlay.(UIElement.Visibility)" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Target="btnStop.(UIElement.Visibility)" Value="Visible" />
                    </VisualState.Setters>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="5*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CaptureElement x:Name="captureElement" Width="320" Height="240" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" />
        <Viewbox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                <Button x:Name="btnPlay" Click="OnStart">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Play" />
                </Button>
                <Button x:Name="btnStop" Click="OnStopAsync" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <SymbolIcon Symbol="Stop" />
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </Viewbox>        
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

---

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Test
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            StartSpeech();
        }

        async void OnStart(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Playing", false);
        }

        async void OnStopAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await this.cameraPreviewManager.StopPreviewAsync();

            VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Stopped", false);
        }
        void OnStop(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.requestStopCancellationToken.Cancel();
        }

        private async void StartSpeech()
        {
            SpeechListener speechRecognition = new SpeechListener();
            speechRecognition.Recognize += OnRecognize;

            // [...] Start speech recognition [...]
        }

        private async void OnRecognize(object sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Result.Confidence.ToString() == "Medium" || e.Result.Confidence.ToString() == "High")
            {
                VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Playing", false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

**SpeechListener.cs**

```
namespace Test {
    class SpeechListener
    {
        public delegate void RecognizeEventHandler(object sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs e);

        public event RecognizeEventHandler Recognize;

        public SpeechListener()
        {
        }

        public async Task PrepareRecognizer()
        {
            recognizer = new SpeechRecognizer();

            // [...]
            recognizer.ContinuousRecognitionSession.ResultGenerated += Recognizer_ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated;

            // [...]
        }

        private void Recognizer_ContinuousRecognitionSession_ResultGenerated(SpeechContinuousRecognitionSession sender, SpeechContinuousRecognitionResultGeneratedEventArgs args)
        {
            Recognize?.Invoke(this, args);
        }
    }
}
```

If I manually press the button, "OnStart" is called, and the "GoToState" is well executed.

If I talk, the callback "OnRecognize" is called, and the call to "GoToState" throw a system exception...

Any clue on that ? I'm not a real C# expert...

Thanks !

---

**EDIT**
@Nico Zhu [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47049746/1348124) pointing out the problem, and my specific case problem is resolved in comments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The speech recognition is ok ; a button to start the camera is ok too. But, call to VisualStateManager.GoToState() on an speech event callback fail :/

Because events raised by the speech recognizer occur on a background thread, create a reference to the dispatcher for updates to the UI thread.

```
if (e.Result.Confidence.ToString() == "Medium" || e.Result.Confidence.ToString() == "High")
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
     {
         VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Playing", false);
     });
}
```

For more, please refer to [Continuous dictation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/input-and-devices/enable-continuous-dictation#initialization).

Comment: Thanks, I'm sure you've pointing out the problem, but in my case, `CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread()` is null... So, I suppose this call is did in a non-UI thread. Maybe because it's a callback from a background thread event ? I'll try with `CoreApplication::MainView`...

Comment: Yes. you could use  `Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal,()=> { });` in the MainPage.

Comment: It works, so what's the difference between

    `await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.N‌​ormal,()=> { });`

and

   `await CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.N‌​ormal,()=> { });` ?

Comment: The [`Dispatcher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.dependencyobject#Windows_UI_Xaml_DependencyObject_Dispatcher) is current Page's property. And the [`CoreApplication.MainView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Windows.ApplicationModel.Core.CoreApplication.MainView)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETCore%2CVersion%3Dv5.0)%3Bk(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue) is app level.